# What does "chekitana" mean in this verse?

Tags: mahabharata, rig-veda, sanskrit, translation

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc831430.html

> **Rig Veda 2.33.15**
>
> Sanskrit text [Accents, Plain, Transliterated]:
>
> ए॒वा ब॑भ्रो वृषभ चेकितान॒ यथा॑ देव॒ न हृ॑णी॒षे न हंसि॑ ।
> ह॒व॒न॒श्रुन्नो॑ रुद्रे॒ह बो॑धि बृ॒हद्व॑देम वि॒दथे॑ सु॒वीरा॑: ॥
>
> evā babhro vṛṣabha cekitāna yathā deva na hṛṇīṣe na haṃsi |
> havanaśrun no rudreha bodhi bṛhad vadema vidathe suvīrāḥ ||
>
> English translation:
> “Cherisher of the world, showerer (of benefits), omniscient and divine (Rudra), hearer of our invocation, so consider us on this occasion, that you may not be irate, nor slay us; but that, blessed with excellent descendants, we may worthily glorify you at this sacrifice.”

A warrior called Chekitana fights on the Pandava side in the Mahabharata.  Is his name related to the sense in which it is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the Cekitana from the Mahabharata: **it's simply a Sanskrit word that means 'intelligent.'** (See [this dictionary](https://learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=cekitana&dir=au), or [this word-by-word translation of the hymn](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Code_Agni/m-GHDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Rig%20Veda%202.33.15%20cekitana&pg=PA145&printsec=frontcover))

The translation from WisdomLib uses the word 'omniscient' instead- probably because it's a 'stronger' adjective, more fitting of describing Rudra. But the idea is the same.

(As a side note, the character in the Mahabharata named Cekitana was so named *for his intelligence* [according to the Bhagavad Gita](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Bhagavad_Gita/GxUJAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=cekitana,%20the%20intelligent%20one))